# Add class to multiple divs depending on click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the scenario. My client wants to be able to change the colour theme of the website I'm designing for him.
I have 4 divs that, when clicked will change the border-colour of another 4 divs. Each click event will change the divs to a different colour depending on which one was clicked.

I thought using some jQuery would solve it but I must be doing something wrong! Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
$('.btn1').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour2, colour3, colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour1');
});

$('.btn2').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour1, colour3, colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour2');
});

$('.btn3').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour1, colour2, colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour3');
});

 $('.btn4').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour1, colour2, colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour4');
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your HTML too, and a jsFiddle.net example when possible.

Comment: So, what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: How does it behave???
What's wrong???

Answer (score 4):

Take the commas out of your remove class

```
$('.btn1').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour2 colour3 colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour1');
});

$('.btn2').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour1 colour3 colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour2');
});

$('.btn3').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour1 colour2 colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour3');
});

 $('.btn4').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('colour1 colour2 colour4');
    $('.box').addClass('colour4');
});
```

Note: you can just call `.removeClass()` to get rid of all of the classes but if you have more classes on box than just those three it will delete them all. Read more at http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 0):

Read the doc : http://api.jquery.com/removeClass ;)

```
//$('.box').removeClass('colour2, colour3, colour4');
$('.box').removeClass('colour2 colour3 colour4');
```